# Run Pool inside process

Tags: python, rabbitmq, multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing in Python. I have some classes each representing some task to be done. A small snippet of class structure is shown below

```
class TaskA():
    parallel_limit = 2       # Max number of process in Pool
    time_limit = 1           # Denotes time taken to perform some operation
    queue_name = 'read_here' # RabbitMQ queue to provide data for consumption

    # Starts a pool of processes listening on queue 
    def start_process_pool(self):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=self.parallel_limit)
        for i in range(0, self.parallel_limit):
            pool.apply_async(self.consume)

        try:
            while True:
                continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print(' [*] Exiting...')
            pool.terminate()
            pool.join()

    # Reads from queue and performs some operation
    def consume(self):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()

        channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name, durable=True)
        channel.basic_consume(queue=self.queue_name, on_message_callback=self.perform_operation, auto_ack=True)

        print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
        channel.start_consuming()

    # Performing some operation
    def perform_operation(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] %r received %r" % (multiprocessing.current_process(), body,))
        time.sleep(self.time_limit)
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

I am able to run this task in Pool. Problem arises when I have multiple Tasks and I need to run each one of them in pool. I am thinking to fork a process for each task and then start pool of process from that, but am unable to figure out how to do it. Any contribution will be of much help.

Comment: I'm just asking but why you dont consider using multithreading instead multiprocessing ?

Comment: Tasks perform some CPU intensive operation and I require them to work in parallel. Whereas threads doesn't run in parallel due to GIL

Comment: Can you please provide a more in depth explanation of the architecture? How many type of tasks do you need to process? Are those tasks coming from the same RMQ queue or each task type is associated to its queue? What are you trying to achieve with multiprocessing?